# Tkinter integrated with sockets not working! Python, Sockets, Tkinter, threading

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tkinter

I am having this problem, I have a socket server in which I am receiving some info sent by a client, in this part of my implementation I want to display(with Label, tkinter) the info I have just received from the client by clicking on myButton(Tkinter button), but, when I clicked on myButton the tkinter GUI gets frozen, and I have to close it and try again, I am not going beyond this step, if I take out the function myClick and the tkinter stuff and display it just with PRINT("counter"), it works perfectly, but I need to do it with tkinter.
Any suggestion how to do it? pls

In summary, I have this server and I need to display the info is receiving on GUI by clicking on mybutton, if does not receive anything it ends the connection.
Also, I am attaching the cliente code just in case:

```
#SERVER:
import socket
from argparse import _MutuallyExclusiveGroup
from tkinter import *
import hmac
import hashlib
import time

HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=6595

root = Tk()
root.title("Server")
root.geometry("300x100")

#Code for the socket
server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST,PORT))
server.listen()

def myClick():
    communication_socket, address = server.accept()
    while True:
        counter=communication_socket.recv(1024)
        if not counter: break
        counter=counter.decode('utf-8')
        myLabel.config(text=f"Message from client is {counter}")


myButton = Button(root, text="Display the counter sent", command=myClick, padx=10, pady=5, fg="black", bg="white")
myButton.pack()
myLabel=Label(root)
myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

```
# Cliente code:
from argparse import _MutuallyExclusiveGroup
from ast import Delete
from tkinter import *
import hmac
import hashlib
import time
from turtle import width
from xml.dom.pulldom import END_DOCUMENT
import socket

HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=6595

#Code for the socket
cli=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

root=Tk()
root.title("Client")
root.geometry("200x100")


cli.connect((HOST,PORT))
key="800070FF00FF08012"
key=bytes(key,'utf-8')
x=0
def button_click():  
    global x
    global key
    x +=1
    msg=bytes(f'{x}','utf-8')
    digest = hmac.new(key, msg,"sha256").digest()
    key=key.replace(key,digest)

    offset = digest[19] & 0xF
    code = digest[offset : offset + 4]
    code = int.from_bytes(code, "big") & 0x7FFFFFFF
    code = code % 1000000
    code="{:06d}".format(code)    

    myLabel.config(text=code)
    counter=str(x)
    cli.send(counter.encode('utf-8'))
    count.config(text=counter)
    

OTP=Button(root,text="Generate OTP",padx=20,pady=10,command=button_click)
OTP.pack()
myLabel=Label(root)
myLabel.pack()
count=Label(root)
count.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try running your server's `myClick()` function in a separate thread so as not to block tkinter

```
# some code has been omitted for brevity
from threading import Thread


def myClick():
    communication_socket, address = server.accept()
    while True:
        counter=communication_socket.recv(1024)
        if not counter: break
        counter=counter.decode('utf-8')
        myLabel.config(text=f"Message from client is {counter}")


def myclick_runner():
    mc_thread = Thread(
        target = myClick,  # your myClick function
        args = (,),
        daemon = True,
    )
    mc_thread.start()
```

Then modify your button's `command` to call `myclick_runner` to start the thread

```
myButton = Button(
    root, 
    text="Display the counter sent",
    command=myclick_runner,  # change this to the thread runner function
    padx=10, 
    pady=5, 
    fg="black", 
    bg="white",
)
```